# After loading KerasClassifier, on running predict() get error 'KerasClassifier' object has no attribute 'classes_'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to save and re-load a KerasClassifier model using the below code:

```
def baseline_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=80, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax')) # output layer, with number of classes
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01), metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model.model.save('model')

#re-load model
model2 = KerasClassifier(build_fn=baseline_model, epochs=100)
model2.model = load_model('model')

preds = model2.predict(testX)
```

The model seems to save ok but when I re-load it and try to generate predictions, I get the following error: 'KerasClassifier' object has no attribute 'classes_'

I'm following the steps in the documentation so I'm not sure why this isn't working.
I did fit the model and use it successfully for prediction prior to saving it.

** Update: I also tried leaving out the line:

```
model2 = KerasClassifier(build_fn=baseline_model, epochs=100)
```

and just running

```
model2.model = load_model('model')
```

but then I get

```
name 'model2' is not defined
```

Comment: KerasClassifier is not a sklearn estimator, it's a simple wrapper from keras library. it hasn't 'classes_' attribute

Comment: So how do I save and reload the model such that I can use it to generate predictions? The predict function works fine before the model is saved and reloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to just reload the model and generate predictions from it, then you don't need the `KerasClassifier` as it justs converts your Keras model to a `scikit-learn` model. So you can remove the lines:

```
model2 = KerasClassifier(build_fn=baseline_model, epochs=100)
model2.model = load_model('model')
```

and instead just write this:

```
model2 = load_model('model')
```

You can then run your `model2.predict(testX)` as normal.

Comment: Thanks, this works as long as I don't use the wrapper to train the model in the first place so I'm just going to do it without the wrapper

Comment: Glad to help you. You can mark the answer as accepted if it solved your issue .